# Display the taxonomy terms hierarchy with count of reference nodes added to it

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I am displaying taxonomy terms in a hierarchical way in a view, I am facing an issue here the parent taxonomy is getting associated with each child terms separately, please find the screenshot.

[image]

I want it to be displayed like this

Electronics

--computers

--mobiles

--tablets

Fashion

--mens

--womens

--kids

This is my view, basically I am displaying the count of nodes added to the taxonomy term of another content type.

> [image]

Comment: If you want a tree, why don't you set display format to tree?

Comment: I have installed the tree view module, and while selecting a format, i am getting the tree adjacency option while selecting that, then after I am getting another window with "Main field" and "Parent filed", I am confused what to select there.

Comment: Well, glad you went that far. If you could update your question with what you got (settings and result) we might be able to recognize what's wrong.

Comment: Please find the screenshot of the options I am having here. [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/A69r7.jpg  There is a other drop down named "Parent field" with same two fields.